# With "Xee" I can no longer display photos in the new macOS Ventura "Lockdown Mode", but with Preview it works

Tags: photos, preview, ventura, privacy

With Xee (from App Store, formerly Open Source) I can't display photos anymore in the new macOS Ventura Lockdown Mode, but with Preview it works.

Screenshot of a photo in my collection:

[image]

Is there a config I can modify or do I have to send a bug report to the developer?

Comment: Did you reach out to the vendor on this, what was the reply?

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same problem with Xee, which I've used for years.
I've found another app, which is actually free and in the App store - Pixea. Works well :)

Answer (score 3):

Same issue here. I have emailed their support to see if i need to upgrade to version 3.5.4 but haven't received any response yet. According to the AppStore , version 3.5.3 is the latest one. However, they have version 3.5.4 on their website, and it appears that I would have to purchase it separately.

Comment: The support also ignored my mail

Comment: The same happened to me. I've written a couple of times already without answer. The version that is published on the website is not working anyways.